Riemann integrability for step function
Here is the problem:

Fix $c\in\mathbb{R}$ and define $g:[0,2]\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$g(x)=\begin{cases}2 &\text{if } 0\le x<1\\c &\text{if } x=1\\ 1&\text{if } 1< x\le 2.\\\end{cases}$$
Show that $g\in\mathcal{R}[0,2]$ and evaluate its integral. (You'll see that it doesn't depend on $c$.)

Here is my working so far:
Let $\mathcal{P}=\{([x_{i-1},x_i],t_i)\}_{i=1}^n$ be tagged partition of $[0,2]$. Suppose $x_{k-1}\le 1\le x_k$ for some $k$.
Let $\mathcal{P}_1=\{([x_{i-1},x_i],t_i)\}_{i=1}^{k-1}$ and $\mathcal{P}_2=\{([x_{i-1},x_i],t_i)\}_{i=k+1}^{n}$.
Then $S(g;\mathcal{P})=S(g;\mathcal{P}_1)+g(t_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})+S(g;\mathcal{P}_2)$
Then I stuck here, so my question is that how can I proceed here. I want to apply the Riemann Integration Criterion here (so I think that post doesn't answer my question), but I am not sure how to choose the $\delta_\epsilon$ such that if $\|\mathcal{P}\|<\delta_\epsilon$ then $|S(g;\mathcal{P})-3|<\epsilon$. Neither does this post (found using MSE's search engine on the query Riemann integrability of step functions), because the "insert sneaky use of triangle inequality here" in it is exactly what I want to see the details as well.

As a general rule of thumb , a monotone function is Riemann integrable , and this fact can be proved generally by Riemann's Criterion for integrability. Then , you can use the domain splitting property + the fact that a function which differs at only one point on an interval has the same integral as the original function.

I got it intuitively but can you show me how to prove such property? I know the integral is supposed to be 3 but I fail to show it by the Riemann integration criterion

@Anne Bauval I think that post doesn't answer my question because I want to apply Riemann integration criterion to show it, instead of using the lower and upper sums.

@Anne Bauval I have edited the post.

@Anne Bauval I am sorry not, the "insert sneaky use of triangle inequality here" in that post is exactly what I want to see the details as well.

You were on the right track:
$$S(g;P)-3=2(x_{k-1}-0)+g(t_k)(x_k-x_{k-1})+1(2-x_k)-\left(2(1-0)+1(2-1)\right)$$
$$=(g(t_k)-2)(1-x_{k-1})+(g(t_k)-1)(x_k-1)$$
hence
$$|S(g;P)-3|\le\max(|g(t_k)-2|,|g(t_k)-1|)\ (x_k-x_{k-1})$$
with $g(t_k)\in\{2,c,1\}$ and $x_k-x_{k-1}\le\delta$, i.e.
$$|S(g;P)-3|\le\max(1,|c-2|,|c-1|)\ \delta.$$
